# How single line Java comment is accepted without starting by //?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, compilation, comments

When I put some `comments` on my `Java` code
I miss to put `//` in the start of the comment line (its content: url)
I expect compilation error *but i surprised the comment line is accepted*!
Note: I use Java7

```
// below single line java comment is accepted without starting by //
https://www.google.com/
```

Kindly any explanation?

Comment: if I'm not mistaken, because it is started by a label

Comment: `https:` is a valid label (see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html), the rest is a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Stultuske comment
Yes - thats is accepted because

1. `https:` conidered as a `java label` then the reaming part
2. `//www.google.com/` conidered as a valid java comment

.

```
// below single line java comment is accepted without starting by //
https://www.google.com/
for(..,..,..){

}
```